# Checking if network has connection errors

Tags: network, gis-principle, connectivity-analysis, pipe-network, water

I have given a network of a city in dwg.
I made a dxf that only contains the network itself, and created a layer for every type of pipe (like 25KPE, 80KPE etc...).

How do I check if the network is drawn correctly?

I try to find every error I can, but im afraid the services pipes are either just a little bit shorter, or longer, and not connecting to the main pipe properly.

I'll have to use this network in EPANET later.

Comment: You had tags for QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop but do not mention either software in your question body. In any event, questions asking for the best of anything are likely to be closed for seeking opinions because they tend to act as polls.

Comment: Im not seeking an opinion, i have no idea how to do it, im still in school...

Comment: Perhaps review these previous Q&As on connectivity, and focus on the ones for the software you wish to test first: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connectivity-analysis?tab=Votes